# Log4j JPA Appender

Tags: java, jpa, logging, log4j

I am trying to save some Log Events with log4j's JPA Appender , I've followed the tutorial 
[here (JPAAppender)](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JPAAppender).

But when I am testing the logger , I get some log4j errors/warnings about the log4j.properties :

```
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 2 and column 31

log4j:WARN Document root element "Configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "null".

log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 2 and column 31

log4j:WARN Document is invalid: no grammar found.

log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Supposing that the problem is at log4j.properties file , any help??
Thanks.

Comment: Where did you place your log4j properties?

Comment: i define it at vm options

Comment: -Dlog4j.configuration=../log4j.xml

Comment: can you try one thing? Remove the vm option, put the log4j.prop... in the "bin" folder, where all your classes reside. And check if it is working. This is a TEMP step, just to make sure your appender is working.

Comment: no luck , but in this case it totally ignores the .properties and get the default configuration for hibernate and spring loggers

Comment: there might be a conflict at slf4j - log4j binding

Comment: well actually when i run the project at tomcat , i get the correct log messages(as defined in log4j.properties)

Comment: the problem occurs when i try to run the Logger in test mode , thats why i pass the configuration log4j file to vm options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with JDBC appender  , i used the command :

log4j.appender.JDBC.sql=INSERT INTO ....

I just pass the requested parameters to the insert query ,nevertheless i have persistence configured.
 Thanks to log4j.MDC

[MDC tutorial](http://www.fiveminutes.eu/logging-custom-parameters-with-log4j/)